# Display .txt file with php

Tags: php, html, css, text

I have an auto-generated  .txt file that looks likes this:

```
SamAccountName Name           PasswordLastSet     
-------------- ----           ---------------    
spiderman      Parker, Peter  7/7/2019 11:18:20 PM
ironman        Stark, Tony    1/17/2006 4:49:32 AM

There are 2 users.
```

I now display this into my website using:

```
<?php
    $file = 'c:\display.txt';
    $f = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($f))
    {
        echo fgets($f)."<br />";
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
```

But it gets formatted like this:

```
SamAccountName Name PasswordLastSet
-------------- ---- ---------------
spiderman Parker, Peter 7/7/2019 11:18:20 PM
ironman Stark, Tony 1/17/2006 4:49:32 AM


There are 2 users.
```

This way, it's very hard to read the table properly.
Why is that so? What causes HTML/PHP to read the file differently than it is?

Comment: So you would want to format it just like Stack Overflow does, right here, in the very first question block. (→ Inspect Element)

Comment: You should show what you tried and explain *how* it's "not working". As it stands, this is "too broad" according to site guidelines (see the [help] if you need to review them).

Answer (score 2):

you can add [pre](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag

```
<?php
$file = 'c:\display.txt';
$f = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
echo "<pre>";
while(!feof($f))
{
    echo fgets($f);
}
echo "</pre>";
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take readfile and set the correct header

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
readfile("display.txt");
```

or embed readfile in a pre-tag

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
readfile("display.txt");
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Your first code seems to work, but the whole website gets formatted plain. How can I do this with only my text?

Comment: The content type can only be set once for a website.
If the website needs content-type text / html you have to use the variant with <pre>.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:text/plain');


$file = new SplFileObject("display.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo $file->fgets().PHP_EOL;
}
```